# dask dataframe to spark not working the same way as pandas dataframe to spark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, dask, python-xarray

I'm reading in some windspeed data from netcdf files. This produces an xarray dataset which I can convert to pandas and/or dask dataframes. Ultimately I want to convert to dask dataframes then to pyspark due to the volume of data. However when converting from dask to spark I'm receiving an error which I don't when doing the equivalent pandas to spark. See below for some code.

### Pandas first

```
df=u10.isel(time0=0).to_dataframe().reset_index()
print(df.head())
print("=======================================================")
print(df.dtypes)
print("=======================================================")
pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df) 
pyspark_df.show(5)


   lon    lat      time0  eastward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0  0.0  90.00 2021-03-01                       -0.375   
1  0.0  89.75 2021-03-01                       -7.000   
2  0.0  89.50 2021-03-01                       -7.125   
3  0.0  89.25 2021-03-01                       -7.250   
4  0.0  89.00 2021-03-01                       -7.250   

   eastward_wind_at_10_metres  northward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0                     -0.1875                       -0.1250   
1                     -5.0625                        0.7500   
2                     -5.1875                        0.8125   
3                     -5.3750                        1.0625   
4                     -6.0000                        1.5625   

   northward_wind_at_10_metres  
0                       0.0000  
1                       0.0625  
2                       0.1250  
3                       0.3750  
4                       1.1250  
=======================================================
lon                                    float64
lat                                    float64
time0                           datetime64[ns]
eastward_wind_at_100_metres            float32
eastward_wind_at_10_metres             float32
northward_wind_at_100_metres           float32
northward_wind_at_10_metres            float32
dtype: object
=======================================================
+---+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|lon|  lat|              time0|eastward_wind_at_100_metres|eastward_wind_at_10_metres|northward_wind_at_100_metres|northward_wind_at_10_metres|
+---+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|0.0| 90.0|2021-03-01 00:00:00|                     -0.375|                   -0.1875|                      -0.125|                        0.0|
|0.0|89.75|2021-03-01 00:00:00|                       -7.0|                   -5.0625|                        0.75|                     0.0625|
|0.0| 89.5|2021-03-01 00:00:00|                     -7.125|                   -5.1875|                      0.8125|                      0.125|
|0.0|89.25|2021-03-01 00:00:00|                      -7.25|                    -5.375|                      1.0625|                      0.375|
|0.0| 89.0|2021-03-01 00:00:00|                      -7.25|                      -6.0|                      1.5625|                      1.125|
+---+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

### Now for dask

```
ddf=u10.isel(time0=0).to_dask_dataframe()
print(ddf.head())
print("=======================================================")
print(ddf.dtypes)
print("=======================================================")
pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(ddf) 
pyspark_df.show(5)

 lon    lat      time0  eastward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0  0.0  90.00 2021-03-01                       -0.375   
1  0.0  89.75 2021-03-01                       -7.000   
2  0.0  89.50 2021-03-01                       -7.125   
3  0.0  89.25 2021-03-01                       -7.250   
4  0.0  89.00 2021-03-01                       -7.250   

   eastward_wind_at_10_metres  northward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0                     -0.1875                       -0.1250   
1                     -5.0625                        0.7500   
2                     -5.1875                        0.8125   
3                     -5.3750                        1.0625   
4                     -6.0000                        1.5625   

   northward_wind_at_10_metres  
0                       0.0000  
1                       0.0625  
2                       0.1250  
3                       0.3750  
4                       1.1250  
=======================================================
lon                                    float32
lat                                    float32
time0                           datetime64[ns]
eastward_wind_at_100_metres            float32
eastward_wind_at_10_metres             float32
northward_wind_at_100_metres           float32
northward_wind_at_10_metres            float32
dtype: object
=======================================================
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18808/850613924.py in <module>
      4 print(ddf.dtypes)
      5 print("=======================================================")
----> 6 pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(ddf)
      7 pyspark_df.show(5)
...
...
...
  1063 
   1064     else:
-> 1065         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
   1066 
   1067     fields = []

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

if anyone can explain why this is happening and offer a solution that would be great

### Added schema to createdataframe call

```
fields = [
 StructField("lon", FloatType(), True),\
 StructField("lat", FloatType(), True),\
 StructField("time0", TimestampType(), True),\
 StructField("eastward_wind_at_100_metres",FloatType(),True), \
 StructField("eastward_wind_at_10_metres",FloatType(),True), \
 StructField("northward_wind_at_100_metres",FloatType(),True), \
 StructField("northward_wind_at_10_metres",FloatType(),True)  ]
 
schema = StructType(fields)

ddf=u10.isel(time0=0).to_dask_dataframe()
print(ddf.head())
print("=======================================================")
print(ddf.dtypes)
print("=======================================================")
pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(ddf,schema) 
pyspark_df.show(10)

  lon    lat      time0  eastward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0  0.0  90.00 2021-03-01                       -0.375   
1  0.0  89.75 2021-03-01                       -7.000   
2  0.0  89.50 2021-03-01                       -7.125   
3  0.0  89.25 2021-03-01                       -7.250   
4  0.0  89.00 2021-03-01                       -7.250   

   eastward_wind_at_10_metres  northward_wind_at_100_metres  \
0                     -0.1875                       -0.1250   
1                     -5.0625                        0.7500   
2                     -5.1875                        0.8125   
3                     -5.3750                        1.0625   
4                     -6.0000                        1.5625   

   northward_wind_at_10_metres  
0                       0.0000  
1                       0.0625  
2                       0.1250  
3                       0.3750  
4                       1.1250  
=======================================================
lon                                    float32
lat                                    float32
time0                           datetime64[ns]
eastward_wind_at_100_metres            float32
eastward_wind_at_10_metres             float32
northward_wind_at_100_metres           float32
northward_wind_at_10_metres            float32
dtype: object
=======================================================
...
...
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py in verify_struct(obj)
   1394                     verifier(d.get(f))
   1395             else:
-> 1396                 raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
   1397                                         % (obj, type(obj))))
   1398         verify_value = verify_struct

TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'lon' in type <class 'str'>
```

### Full traceback

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5368/3996125343.py in <module>
     15 print(ddf.dtypes)
     16 print("=======================================================")
---> 17 pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(ddf,schema)
     18 pyspark_df.show(10)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    673             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    674                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
--> 675         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    676 
    677     def _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    698             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    699         else:
--> 700             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    701         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    702         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    507         # make sure data could consumed multiple times
    508         if not isinstance(data, list):
--> 509             data = list(data)
    510 
    511         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in prepare(obj)
    680 
    681             def prepare(obj):
--> 682                 verify_func(obj)
    683                 return obj
    684         elif isinstance(schema, DataType):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py in verify(obj)
   1407     def verify(obj):
   1408         if not verify_nullability(obj):
-> 1409             verify_value(obj)
   1410 
   1411     return verify

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py in verify_struct(obj)
   1394                     verifier(d.get(f))
   1395             else:
-> 1396                 raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
   1397                                         % (obj, type(obj))))
   1398         verify_value = verify_struct

TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'lon' in type <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I think the short answer is that you need to tell Spark what types your data are. Spark does its best to guess at the data types in your DataFrame, but it doesn't necessarily know all of them because Dask does its best to avoid having all the data in memory at the same time. This can happen if you have different dtypes in different partitions in your Dask Dataframe. This issue in the Dask issue tracker is related but it's about parquet: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8619

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work for me either: Slightly different error message this time , please see new added output to original post

Comment: Can you show more of the traceback? It's not clear if the error is coming when you try to create the `StructType` or later on.

Comment: Full traceback added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside: are you sure you want spark to process this data? Dask integrated well with xarray and you might well find that the conversion is not worth your while, not least because you will need to duplicate and convert the data and have two cluster systems running.

Short answer: `createDataFrame` supports exactly pandas and not "pandas-like objects" such as dask dataframe. From the docstring:

> ```
>     data : :class:`RDD` or iterable
>         an RDD of any kind of SQL data representation (:class:`Row`,
>         :class:`tuple`, ``int``, ``boolean``, etc.), or :class:`list`, or
>         :class:`pandas.DataFrame`.
> ```

A dask dataframe is made up of lazy partitions, but you are asking spark to send them to spark workers. This is not a simple operation! You *could* decide to create spark dataframes for each of the dask partitions, and concatenate them on the worker side - this would likely achieve what you are after but not be at all efficient.

```
to_spark_df = dask.delayed(spark.createDataFrame)
pieces = dask.compute(*[to_spark_df(d) for d in ddf.to_delayed()])
spark_df = functoos.reduce(pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll, pieces)
```

(note that this is applying union in a chain, there doesn't seem to be a simple concat operation in spark)

Comment: It was slow and I ran into some memory problems but the code did as you said. Cheers